# Somebody can helpme to extract a text with RegExp?

Tags: javascript, regex, extract

today i break my head with a regex. I can't extract a part of text. My text is like this:

```
<!--TEXT[title]-->
sometext 1
<!--END-->
<!--TEXT[title]-->
sometext 2
<!--END-->
```

I want get this in a array

```
["title]-->sometext1"
,"title]-->sometext2"]
```

i have this regex code `mytext.match(/<!--TEXT[([.|\w|\r|\n]+)<!--END-->/m);`

Comment: Is this text inside of some HTML?  If so, don't parse HTML with a regex:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454  Instead, parse the DOM.

Comment: @JackManey That's my favourite answer to anything ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you need a regular expression the following should work:

```
<\!--TEXT\[([^\]]*)\]-->\s*\n(.*)(?!<\!--END-->)
```

If this text is in a DOM it would be much better to parse the DOM however.

Explanation:

```
<\!--TEXT\[ // Match the start.
([^\]]*) // Match (in group 1), everything up until the next ']'
\]-->\s*\n // Match to the end of this line.
(.*) // Match anything (in group 2).
(?!<\!--END-->) // Stop before the end tag is next. (This will mean you get everything up to, but not including the previous line break).
```

Comment: Of course this will fail with nested comments, but this is something the OP should know...

Comment: Yes, if you're dealing with nested comments you want a lexer or a DOM. On the other hand in this particular case it doesn't look like they would be nested (without there being some error).